# select distinct values from table without using session in sqlachemy

Tags: python, sql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have table in sqlalchemy:

```
class Exams(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'exams'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name_of_Exam = db.Column(db.String(140))
    number_of_exam_task = db.Column(db.SmallInteger)
    name_of_exams_task = db.Column(db.String(140))
```

I need to get unique values from first column.My code is:

```
qqq = db.session.query(Exams.name_of_Exam).distinct()
for i in qqq:
    print(i.name_of_Exam)
```

How to make such result withoyt using `db.session`? I tried such thing:

```
qqq = Exams.query.options(load_only("name_of_Exam")).distinct(Exams.name_of_Exam)
for i in qqq:
    print(i.name_of_Exam)
```

and failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure why you would want to-- doing it via session seems clearer and cleaner, but the following should work:

```
    data = Exams.query.with_entities(Exams.name_of_Exam).distinct(Exams.name_of_Exam).all()

    for x in data:
        print(x.name_of_Exam)
```